# Content changeable Dropdownlist from database data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Am loading my user records from database to the table, Am using:

```
foreach ($userArray as $key => $value) {
```

I have isAdmin row which contains 'Y', 'N' data.I need to make dropdownlist from this row.If data in Db is 'Y' other dropdownlist option should be 'N' and v/v. 
Am using `<select id="<?php echo $userArray[$key]["isAdmin"]?>">`

I tried something like that, but  if my data is Y it gives two more options , Y and N, it should be N, how to repair that?Here is my code:

```
<select id="<?php echo $userArray[$key]["isAdmin"]?>">

   <option value="<?php echo $userArray[$key]["isAdmin"]?>">
    <?php echo $userArray[$key]["isAdmin"];  

    if (strcmp($userArray[$key]["isAdmin"],"Y")==0){
?></option>

        <option value="N">N</option> 
        <option value="Y" style="display:none;">Y</option>

<?php 
}
else 
?>

<option value="Y">Y</option>
<option value="N" style="display:none;">N</option>

   </select>
```

I found a solution, here is my code:

```
 <option value="<?php echo $userArray[$key]["isAdmin"]?>">
    <?php echo $userArray[$key]["isAdmin"];  

    if (strcmp($userArray[$key]["isAdmin"],"Y")==0){
?></option>

        <option value="N">N</option> 


<?php 
}

  if (strcmp($userArray[$key]["isAdmin"],"N")==0){

?>

<option value="Y">Y</option>


<?php
}
?>

   </select>
```

Comment: You could add `selected` to one and `disabled` to the other if you want to show the appropriate one as selected and not have the other one selectable - @alexander's method seems the least complicated way to build that though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a if condition in your nav bar checking isAdmin and then echo the other dropdownlist.

```
if($isadmin == "Y"){
echo '?>

//Put Html code here for admin

<?php ';
}else{
echo'?>

//Put Html code here for non admin

<?php';
}
```